# Facebook login Error. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match

Tags: php, .htaccess, facebook-php-sdk

I have error while loging in to my app using facebook SDK.

error says:
*"Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match".*

It's not about missing `session_start()` or double executed `getLoginUrl()` etc.

I just conducted a test and found out that mine `.htaccess` is the problem.
When `.htaccess` is on server FB login returns error. Without `.htaccess` it works just fine.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

That's why you have to take your users and bring it back always in a www version of your site. If you are using only mypage.com, you must to use always www.mypage.com for validate your login into your facebook. In the part that you use the $loginUrl that provides as an example the doc of SDK Facebook, you have to redirect to the user and bring it back to the same page.

I mean, if in your url you put myexample.com/logincallback.php and you are bring the users in a version www.myexample.com/logincallback.php you never finish the validation of facebook for make the token. I will show an example:

```
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $permissions = ['email']; 
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('www.mywebsite.com/logincallback.php', $permissions );
```

When you finish this code, you have to go to your settings app in developers.facebook.com and configure a www version of your website in Settings > Advanced > Deauthorize Callback URL

In this field, write http://www.mywebsite.com/logincallback.php

So, if you are using htaccess for redirect the page to a www version of your site, make sure to use the same URL in the Deauthorize Callback URL and in your getLoginUrl()

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

insert this code

```
$_SESSION['FBRLH_state']=$_GET['state'];
```

after

```
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
```

Comment: When I do that I get "Graph returned an error: This authorization code has been used." instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a static page for Facebook Login and call that page from "Login with Facebook" button. In Facebook Login Page, get the login url and redirect. It will work best. Check full text in the blog post.
http://www.shozab.com/facebook-login-callback-error-cross-site-request-forgery-validation-failed/